# How can I store information in another external file from python in this project?

Tags: python

I'm trying here to program a login system ( I know my code is bad because actually I'm a beginner ), but I don't know how to append the new user and password into another external file separated each one in a line. Here where I have been getting stuck:

```
login_userpass_storage = open("USER_PASSWORD_STORAGE.txt", "r+")

choice = input("Enter 'Create' to create a new account or 'login' to login into your last account: ")

if choice == "Create":
   login_userpass_storage.close ()
   login_userpass_storage2 = open("USER_PASSWORD_STORAGE.txt","w+")
   username = input("Enter a username: ")
   password = input("Enter a new password: ")
   login_userpass_storage.write(str(username))
   login_userpass_storage.write(str(password))
   print(login_userpass_storage.read())
elif choice == "login":
   username = login_userpass_storage.readline()
   password = login_userpass_storage.readline()
   username2 = input("Enter your username: ")
   password2 = input("Enter your password: ")
   if username2 != username or password2 != password:
      print("Invalid username or password")
   else:
      print("Hello" + str(username2))

   print(login_userpass_storage.read())
   ''' This last line of code is just for me just to make sure everything works so it doesn't make 
   any sense in my code'''
```

Comment: I suggest you using database for saving passwords.

Comment: You are using ```login_userpass_storage``` after closing it, i am assuming you want to use ```login_userpass_storage2```